# extjs how to fix 16x16 icons clipped in tabpanel?

Tags: extjs, tabs

It appears that standard 16x16 icons get clipped in the tabs of a default tabpanel.  Even the Sencha [advanced tabs example](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-0/#!/example/tabs/tabs-adv.html) exhibits that behavior:

[image]

What is the preferred method to increase the height of the tabs in the tab bar so the entire icon will be displayed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Answer in Sencha forum](http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?149856-How-to-fix-16x16-icons-clipped-in-tabpanel):

Add this to CSS:

```
.x-tab-default-top button,
.x-tab-default-top .x-tab-inner {
        height: 16px !important;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In one of  my  project, I needed This So Bad. After much trouble i discovered That you can do it inside tabConfig for each tab item but also ensure you modify the height of the tabBar